# What are the pronouns it and them in the following sentence : how much time, money, and effort it takes them?

Tags: pronouns, translation

The text book explains the word "productivity" as following :

> the amount of work that a person, company, etc. does compared with **how much time, money, and effort it takes them**.

Here I cannot understand the part "it takes them"

I am familiar with the verb 'take'. For example

> 'It takes the tragedy of Tom's death for us to meet here'

which is a slight modification of sentence in some script.

I think the following is correct.

> **how much time, money and effort it takes for them to do**

How would you say about my opinion ?

Comment: You are right. It does mean that.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to explain the pronouns is to replace them with what they stand for:

*"the amount of work that a person, company, etc. does compared with how much time, money, and effort **[the work]** takes **[the person, company, etc]**."

Obviously you would never write such a sentence.